# Core Data Applied to a NavigationController

Tags: core-data

```
I would like to set this up:

** UINavigationController **                       ** Core Data **
- RootView (Table of Courses-of-Study)             - [CourseOfStudy entity]
-- didSelectRowAtIndexPath --> DetailView          -- [StudyMaterial entity](list of Qs)
-- DetailView consists of:
--- TextView  (on top)                             --- [Question entity]
--- TableView (on bottom, subview of DetailView)   --- [Answers entity, Distractors entity]

How do relate my courses of study directly with their respective/detail-view/child data?

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row in the Master/Root tableview will represent a particular `CourseOfStudy` object. When the user selects that row, you will know which `CourseOfStudy` object is needed. Create an attribute in DetailView controller to hold a `CourseOfStudy` object. Before you push the DetailView controller onto the NavigationController's stack, set the attribute to the selected `CourseOfStudy` object.

...and you're done. The DetailView controller now has the correct `CourseOfStudy` object and can display it's properties.

Comment: How do I add/delete content into one of the properties?

Comment: You just assign a value to it like any other variable.